# How to check if a sequence is empty in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, sequence

How to check if a sequence is empty in Kotlin? What's the simplest way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you mean literally a `Sequence`, use [`none()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/none.html) without arguments for "is empty" and [`any()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/any.html) for "is not empty".

For other collections, these method names work as well, but there's also
[`isNotEmpty()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/is-not-empty.html). Strangely, there *is* `isEmpty`, but [only for arrays](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/is-empty.html)!

Answer (score 1):

```
!sequence.iterator().hasNext()
```

Comment: I am not sure whether this is the simplest way. I don't know why there isn't an `isEmpty` extension function for sequences.

Comment: Careful with this method. If the sequence is an "only once" sequence, then any successive call to `iterator()` will fail.